# Unable to write nth root

Tags: amsmath, sqrt, root

I would like to write the nth root, it's fairly simple as

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{equation}    
   a = \sqrt[n]{b}
\end{equation}
```

but I get the output as

[image]

Can anybody help me with this. 
Thanks!

Edit: I have added the MWE

As I was preparing the MWE, I noticed that there is a new sqrt definition in the document setup I borrowed.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
\def\sqrt{\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
   a = \sqrt[n]{b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Now how to get the nth root in this new sqrt?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The cause of this anomaly may be the use of some incompatible package.  Please provide a small compilable file beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that results in the problematic output.  That will give us the information we need to debug the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your `MWE`? Please refer this link https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks about how to post `MWE`

Comment: Where is the redefinition coming from? It is quite obvious, that it is incompatible.

Comment: I borrowed the document template and it was in that. Unfortunately I don't know anythinig more about that :(

Comment: Perfect! That was the tweak that was needed